# nested arrays in object input manipulation vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, vue.js, object

Good, I have a form which is loaded by 2 iterations, one to load activities and another iteration that is within months, the problem I have is that when entering text in the input text the value in the other text is doubled input The activities come from the database, and the months that will take a start date and an end date, those months should be assigned an amount. So the problem is that these quantities are doubled, making it impossible to enter data correctly.

This is my code in sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/embed/inspiring-proskuriakova-nb0bk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
<template>
<div class="content">

    <div v-for="(act, index) in actividades" :key="index">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 mt-3">
                <b>Actividad {{act.codigo}}</b> 
                <div class="row" v-for="(pro, index2) in act.programaticas" :key="index2">    
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <br>
                        {{pro.mes}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                         Cantidad  
                        <input type="number" required class="form-control" v-model="pro.cantidad">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
```

```
   export default {
    data () {
        return {
            proyecto:{},            
            actividades:[],
            programaticas:[],
            programatica:{mes:'',cantidad:''},
        }
},
created() {
    this.fetch();
},
methods:{
    async fetch()
    {   
    const proyecto = await 
        Repository.show('proyectos',this.$route.params.proyecto_id);           
        this.proyecto = proyecto.data;

    const actividades=await 
        Repository.show('actividades',this.$route.params.objetivo_id);     
        if(actividades.data.length!=0)
        {
            this.actividades = actividades.data;     
        }
        this.obtenerMeses();
    },

    obtenerMeses()
    {  
        var monthNames = [ "Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio",
        "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre" ];

        var datFrom = new Date(this.proyecto.fecha_inicio);
        var datTo = new Date(this.proyecto.fecha_fin);

        var fromYear =  datFrom.getFullYear();
        var toYear =  datTo.getFullYear();

        var diffYear = (12 * (toYear - fromYear)) + datTo.getMonth();

        for (var i = datFrom.getMonth(); i <= diffYear; i++) {
            this.programatica.mes=monthNames[i%12] + " " + Math.floor(fromYear+(i/12));
            this.programaticas.push(this.programatica);
            this.programatica={mes:'',cantidad:''};
        }

        for(var i2 = 0; i2 < this.actividades.length; i2++)
        {  
             this.actividades[i2].programaticas=this.programaticas;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is:

```js
for(var i2 = 0; i2 < this.actividades.length; i2++)
{  
   this.actividades[i2].programaticas=this.programaticas;
}
```

You declare for each item the reference to *the same array*: `this.programaticas`. You must create the copy for each item. For example:

```js
for(var i2 = 0; i2 < this.actividades.length; i2++)
{  
   this.actividades[i2].programaticas=JSON.parse(JSON.strigify(this.programaticas));
}
```

or better

```js
for(var i2 = 0; i2 < this.actividades.length; i2++)
{
  var list = [] 
  for (var i = datFrom.getMonth(); i <= diffYear; i++) {
    list.push({
      mes: monthNames[i%12] + " " + Math.floor(fromYear+(i/12)),
      cantidad:''
    });
  }
  this.actividades[i2].programaticas = list;
}
```

or change the concept, like one structure for inputs, other for labels

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution.